# What is the difference between "direct_session_runs" and "graph_runs" in tf_serving docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to create some dash boards in splunk using tensorflow-serving docker logs. It returns two metrics for each event that I'm not sure what their difference or meaning is, "direct_session_runs" and "graph_runs"

I've tried looking in the tf documentation but I'm not seeing an explanation of what the values are. I originally thought they would be the same but I'm seeing them occasionally diverge.

```
# TYPE :tensorflow:core:direct_session_runs counter
:tensorflow:core:direct_session_runs{} 82

# TYPE :tensorflow:core:graph_runs counter
:tensorflow:core:graph_runs{} 82
```

Answer (score -1):

"The number of times DirectSession::Run() has been called."

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc

Comment: How is that an answer to the question?

Comment: Given that I don't work for Google nor did I write the TF package, my/your best bet is to look at the easter eggs in the source code. And there you have the notes the authors left.